# How to find the related maven library for a bunch of libraries

Tags: maven

I am requested to port one of a biggest project to maven it has almost 200 - 300 libraries. Do i need to search in http://search.maven.org manually and update it or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: In most case what you need to do is to declare the libraries that your project is directly using.  I believe for your 200-300 libraries, most of them are transitive dependencies for which Maven will take care of.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of maybe OT here depending on your perspective.   But one solution is to, using NetBeans, load your project source into a blank Maven project (using a standard Maven layout), and right click all of the unresolved symbols, choosing the context option "Search Maven repository"...

It will allow you to add the correct dependency and update your pom.xml for you.

The catch is you have to be certain the version of the class is the one you want.   It's not going to be an automated precoess and you'll have to do lots of integration testing...  but that should get you started.

Comment: In accordance with what @Adrian Shum is saying, please start from the "top down" with the process I outline - entry point classes and exposed interfaces to technologies you "directly" use (as opposed to stuff you've added to satisfy what those ones need, etc)